# Hide/Display Next and Prev Button on Custom Slider Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider

I like to hide/show nav buttons based on the slide position. If the slider is at the start I want the Previous button to hide, then when the slider is showing the last item, I want the next button to hide. Both the previous and next buttons should show if the slider is still inbetween. Please note that  `.carousel__item { width: auto; height: auto;}`  is for unique usage reason. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamurgent/qb3cr5x6/)

Please feel free to simply modify the code. Thank you.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
    var $carousel = $(this),
        $carouselContainer = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-container"),
        $carouselList = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-list"),
        $carouselItem = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-item"),
        $carouselButton = $carousel.find(".js-carousel-button"),
        setItemWidth = function(){
            $carouselList.removeAttr("style");
            var curWidth = $($carouselItem[0]).outerWidth() * $carouselItem.length;
            $carouselList.css("width", curWidth);
        },
        slide = function(){
            var $button = $(this),
                dir = $button.data("dir"),
                curPos = parseInt($carouselList.css("left")) || 0,
                moveto = 0,
                containerWidth = $carouselContainer.outerWidth(),
                listWidth = $carouselList.outerWidth(),
                before = (curPos + containerWidth),
                after = listWidth + (curPos - containerWidth);
            if(dir=="next"){
                moveto = (after < containerWidth) ? curPos - after : curPos - containerWidth;
            } else {
                moveto = (before >= 0) ? 0 : curPos + containerWidth;
            }
            $carouselList.animate({
                left: moveto
            });
        };
    $(window).resize(function(){
        setItemWidth();
    });
    setItemWidth();
    
    $carouselButton.on("click", slide);
 
});
```

Comment: Please share some code. it will help community members to understand your issue and help you back.

Comment: @PranSukh that is why I added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamurgent/qb3cr5x6/). Thanks for the heads-up though.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display   `$(".carousel__button--prev").toggle(moveto != 0);`

Comment: @freedomn-m please be kind to assist me on this. I have tried toggling a class based on the comment you shared. Please how can I get it to work?

Comment: @freedomn-m I was able to get the code you shared to hid/show the prev button, but I'm unable to figure out what to do for the next button. Any help?

Comment: You need to determine when it's "at the end"

Comment: @freedomn-m please how? can you edit my fiddle? please help :(

Comment: @freedomn-m when I use this `$(".carousel__button--next").toggle(after != 0);` it works. Problem is that I must add `.carousel__item {flex: 1 0 100px;}` which I am trying to avoid because I need the width of each item to be its content width. What can I do?

Comment: @freedomn-m Many thanks to you. I was able to figure it out in the end. I applied the code you provided and also followed the logic from the article you recommended. Thanks a million. My problem is solved. I don't know how to mark your answer correct, but I imagine it may be impossible from the comment area. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted by yourself - will always be the enduring solution.  Little surprised someone else didn't provide an answer for you though, so glad my comment helped you along the way.